# Indefinite Integral of this Functions

Tags: calculus, integration

$$ I_1= \int \sqrt{x^3+2}\,\, dx $$

$$ I_2= \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3+2}}\,\, dx $$

Using Integration by Parts:

$$ I_1= \int \sqrt{x^3+2}\,\, dx= x\sqrt{x^3+2}-1.5 \int \frac{x^3}{\sqrt{x^3+2}}\,\,dx $$ $\implies$
$$ I_1= \int \sqrt{x^3+2}\,\, dx= x\sqrt{x^3+2}-1.5 \int \frac{x^3+2-2}{\sqrt{x^3+2}}\,\,dx $$ $\implies$

$$ 2.5I_1=x\sqrt{x^3+2}+3I_2 $$

I could not proceed further, Just give me a Hint That's Enough.

Comment: I have some doubts that it can be that easily found. WA suggests [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28x^3%2B2%29^%281%2F2%29&lk=4).

Comment: According to my Calc book, your first integral is mentioned as an example that does NOT have an antiderivative in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: I was looking and wolfram will return elliptic integrals for both so there isn't really an elementary answer

Comment: Ok Fine Thank You all